# Connecting Zaper to Salesforce Sandbox Troubleshoots

Tags: salesforce, zapier

Writing this post because I could not locate much content on troubleshooting specifically for connecting a Salesforce Sandbox as a connected Zapier account.

First troubleshoot issue is that you must select that you wish to connect to a sandbox account from the "advanced options" feature by doing as follows

1) From Zapier dashboard, nagivate to "Connected Accounts"
2) use the search bar with text "add new account", to find Salesforce, selecting this will open a pop-up, you must select "advanced options" and then select "sandbox, instead of production.

Secondly, I had an issue with Privilege error and could not locate a soluton on the forums. Here was my solution -

1) Zapier would constantly default to connecting to an old sandbox. To cause Zapier to allow me the option of selecting a new sandbox, I had to log out of both, Zapier and all Salesforce sandboxes and Productions.

2) Once I logged onto the desired sandbox, I had an error stating I did not have the privileges to perform my requested action, despite being an admin. It turned out the new custom objects I had made in Sandbox did not have any users down as having read/write authorization and even though it was only two custom objects, this was enough to trigger a rejection for the whole Zapier-Sandbox account linking. I made a permission set for the new objects, assigned them to all users and allowed all read/write access (note, use more appropriate security settings for your organisation). This finally fixed the issue and I could now test zaps on my Sandbox.

Answer (score 0):

First troubleshoot issue is that you must select that you wish to connect to a sandbox account from the "advanced options" feature by doing as follows

1) From Zapier dashboard, nagivate to "Connected Accounts" 2) use the search bar with text "add new account", to find Salesforce, selecting this will open a pop-up, you must select "advanced options" and then select "sandbox, instead of production.

Secondly, I had an issue with Privilege error and could not locate a soluton on the forums. Here was my solution -

1) Zapier would constantly default to connecting to an old sandbox. To cause Zapier to allow me the option of selecting a new sandbox, I had to log out of both, Zapier and all Salesforce sandboxes and Productions.

2) Once I logged onto the desired sandbox, I had an error stating I did not have the privileges to perform my requested action, despite being an admin. It turned out the new custom objects I had made in Sandbox did not have any users down as having read/write authorization and even though it was only two custom objects, this was enough to trigger a rejection for the whole Zapier-Sandbox account linking. I made a permission set for the new objects, assigned them to all users and allowed all read/write access (note, use more appropriate security settings for your organisation). This finally fixed the issue and I could now test zaps on my Sandbox.